# Maven - Build failure : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I've a problem with the following dependency in my pom.xml where org.springframework.version = 3.1.0.RELEASE:

```
<!-- Spring MVC framework -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

When I execute the command line 'mvn clean install', I've the following error :

```
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 1.052s
 [INFO] Finished at: Sat Dec 07 15:49:04 CET 2013
 [INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) on project myGoogleAppEngine: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\EclipseProjects\myGoogleAppEngine\target\myGoogleAppEngine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib\spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

By seeing on http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/3.1.0.RELEASE , there aren't any errors in my dependency.

I tried to close the project and Eclipse and open again Eclipse but it doesn't work.

Do you have any solutions ?

Thank you

Comment: The jar is locked by another process. You could try to delete it through the file-explorer. If this doesn't work, you could try to end a process through the task manager, but you need to know which process. In the end you can always log off, log in and delete it if you can't find any other solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442862/maven-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-clean-plugin2-4-1)