# maven clean install Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins

Tags: maven-3

From Eclipse mars version, pom.xml - Run As - maven clean and i got the following error message with Build Failure.
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project testing-framework: 
Execution default-clean of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 -> org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6: 
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:pom:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]

Comment: I had the same problem and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37696887/5300182) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by killing java.exe process in Task Manager and re-excuting maven clean install.

Answer (score 0):

> Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org

sounds like a networking issue. Maybe check wether you need to supply proxy information within your settings.xml. [Here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)'s the documentation on how to supply one.

Alternativly, Eclipse might expose its own proxy settings to its Maven integration, but I'm not sure about that, I only use Maven from console. Still, its worth the check and maybe the config.