# How to close/unshare a file being used by another user?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

My .NET app updates a certain .xls file located in a shared folder inside the domain. Using VB.NET, how can I check if that file is being used by another user and unshare/close it, so my code can update the file properly?
NOTE:.Exe file(my app) will be executed in the server where shared folder is.

Answer (score 2):

Windows and NTFS is designed to prevent this scenario.  Unless you:

- Get the Excel application which is holding the .xls file open to close it
- Shut down the server's network connection assuming the Excel file is opened by client PCs - a highly undesirable step to take
- Discover the PC on which the Excel.exe instance is running and use the Windows `Taskkill` command-line command to kill all Excel.exe instances (since you won't necessarily know which one has it open) on the machine - another undesirable step to take
- Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/320161/1687613), but this uses third-party utilities, and doesn't explain *how* these utilities do what they do though you may be able to `Process.Start` them.

you just *can't* get Windows/NTFS to release the file lock.

A possible alternative that I'm not sure will work with an xls (as opposed to an xls_) is to make the file [shared](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-HP010096833.aspx), though this has some limitations.

Comment: Ok, I get it, however I must say I'm the owner of that file and if I execute the file in my machine it should be possible to unshare that file...since it is exactly the same that if I just unshare the folder manually. I just want to automate the "unshare" process, I know how to do it using .bat, but is there a way to do it using .NET?.

Comment: Owner or not, Windows won't easily allow you to remove a file lock.  If you can unlock the file with a .bat file, you can get .NET to run the bat file.  Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178872/run-batch-file-in-vb-net. 

I'm afraid I haven't heard of anyone using .NET to unlock a file directly, or if they are, they aren't sharing their knowledge.

Comment: Just to be curious, is there way (via code) to get the PC on which EXCEL.EXE is running? so I can use Windows Taskiller inside a .bat and call it

Comment: You could look at http://serverfault.com/questions/109276/how-to-tell-what-computer-has-a-file-open-on-a-network-share to get information on finding which *user* has the file open, and http://serverfault.com/questions/44862/best-way-to-find-the-computer-a-user-last-logged-on-from to find what PC they logged in to.